# How to get the defined coordinates of nodes?

Tags: latex, coordinates, tikz

In the following example I would expect the vertical lines of the rectangles to be aligned, but for some reason they are not. I assume this is because not the actual coordinates of the nodes are used, but they in include some kind of offset. I also tried using `.base` for each of the nodes in the rectangle command, but it didn't solve that problem.

How can I access the actual coordinates I defined in the nodes?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (d) at (0, 7) [anchor=west] {$D_i$};
\node (c) at (0, 5) [anchor=west] {$C^j$}; 
\node (b) at (0, 3) [anchor=west] {$B_k$}; 
\node (a) at (0, 1) [anchor=west] {$A$};
\draw ($(a)+(-1, -1)$) rectangle ($(b)+(1,1)$);
\draw ($(c)+(-1, -1)$) rectangle ($(d)+(1,1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Update: I realize the alignment problem can be solved by defining the cooridnates first like in the following code, but I'd be still interested to hear how to extract the actual coordinates from a node.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (d) at (0, 7);
\coordinate (c) at (0, 5);
\coordinate (b) at (0, 3);
\coordinate (a) at (0, 1);
\node  at (d) [anchor=west] {$D_i$};
\node  at (c) [anchor=west] {$C^j$}; 
\node  at (b) [anchor=west] {$B_k$}; 
\node  at (a) [anchor=west] {$A$};
\draw ($(a)+(-1, -1)$) rectangle ($(b)+(1,1)$);
\draw ($(c)+(-1, -1)$) rectangle ($(d)+(1,1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- instead of manually calculating the corners of the rectangle with `($(a)+(-1, -1)$)` etc, you could use the corners of nodes with `(a.south west)` etc.
- to avoid misalignment, make sure all your nodes have the same size by specifying a big enough minimum width and height
- it might be more convenient to position the nodes below each other with the `positioning` library

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm}]
\node (d) at (0, 7)   {$D_i$};
\node[below of=d] (c) {$C^j$}; 
\node[below of=c,anchor=north] (b) {$B_k$}; 
\node[below of=b] (a) {$A$};
\draw (a.south west) rectangle (b.north east);
\draw (c.south west) rectangle (d.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tips for solving my problem. I'd still be curious though whether/how it is possible to extract the coordinates used in the definition of a node afterwards!

Comment: You get the coordinates of a node from the various anchors, e.g. `a.south west` or `a.center`. If you need them in numerical form, you can use `let`, see the example in section `4.1.3 The Circle Around A` of the user guide

Comment: Right, I'm was aware of that, but none of them seemed to produce the same result as replacing a `\node` with `\coordinate` though (I assumed `a.base` would produce the point defined by the coordinate.). Thanks for the refernce using the `let` command, it looks quite useful.

Comment: @flawr `a.base` will give you the horizontal center and vertical position of the baseline of the text inside the node.